# Is it safe to use Swift's String(Int) to generate ASCII integers without separators?

Tags: swift, number-formatting

Are there any circumstances where a basic Swift String from Int call, e.g. `String(10000)`, would result in a String that's not `"10000"`? Does current locale affect the result and if it does, are there any locales where it would use characters other than ASCII `0`–`9` or that would add thousand separators etc?

I've used `NSNumberFormatter` in the past to ensure `en_US_POSIX` Locale but `String(n)` is a lot nicer to read than

```
let formatter = …
formatter.string(from: n as NSNumber)!
```

The documentation for Int.description is, well, terse.

Comment: I think the answer is probably no, but whenever I need a string in a specific format I always force the format, using e.g. a formatter.

Comment: `String(someInt)` ultimately calls `uint64ToStringImpl ` in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/stubs/Stubs.cpp#L83, so one answer is "currently: yes, it is safe". (And I doubt that will change in the future.)